# SeekBar : Change Tick color

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-seekbar

I am using `Discrete` seekbar. I want to change the color of inactive tick marks.

[image]

Here's my `SeekBar`

```xml
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="10"
    android:progress="7" />
```

**What have I tried so far?**

- Applied custom style that extends `Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete` and tried applying `colorControl*`
- Applied `android:tickMark` with different states `state_focused=false, state_activated=false`, but I think it applies to all tick marks.

**Question?**

How can I set  color of the `SeekBar`'s tick marks for the inactive portion of the track?

**Note**

I am aware about the `MaterialComponent`'s `Slider`. My requirement is to make it possible with `SeekBar`.

Answer (score 2):

You could set `android:tickMark` drawable, but I don't think it supports state list for each of the ticksmark. As you mentioned Material Slider has [tickColorActive](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider#attr_Slider_tickColorActive) & [tickColorInactive](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider#attr_Slider_tickColorInactive) attrs.
If implementing the behavior with the traditional seek bar is a must, You may need to play with `onDraw` method of the same.